# Adding space before and after operators in java string

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying for the last few hours to put spaces on both sides of an operator in a string. The string looks like this `65+4*5/6` but I want it to look like this `65 + 4 * 5 / 6`. The only way that I could accomplish that was by writing some code that doesn't look all that great.

```java
String expression = "65+4*5/6";

expression = expression.replaceAll("\\+", " + ");
expression = expression.replaceAll("-", " - ");
expression = expression.replaceAll("/", " / ");
expression = expression.replaceAll("\\*", " * ");
System.out.println(expression);
```

Is there a way that I could condense these four regular expressions into one regular expression? Can I have all the characters in one regular expression and use the result of it in the replacement text?

Comment: Use `.replaceAll("\\s*([-*/+])\\s*", " $1 ")`

Comment: I would just have used what you have.

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this.  It works as follows:

- `[-*/+]` matches on any single character between the brackets.
- `$0` returns the matched character so the character is replaced by the same character surrounded by spaces.

```
String expression = "65+4*5/6";
expression = expression.replaceAll("[-*/+]", " $0 ");
System.out.println(expression);
```

Prints

```
65 + 4 * 5 / 6
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't in the expression.  I'll add it.  Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't in the "test suite"   `String expression = "65+4*5/6"` but it _was_ in the "implementation".

Comment: Well, so it was.  Spaced that one out.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s = "65+4*5/6";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?=[+\\-*\\/])|(?<=[+\\-*\\/])", " "));
}
```

output :

```
65 + 4 * 5 / 6
```

explain :

```
(?=[+\\-*\\/]) : any emty followed by +,-,*or/
| : or
(?<=[+\\-*\\/]) : any empty leaded by +,-,*or/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize whitespacing around the arithmetic operators using

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\s*([-*/+])\\s*", " $1 ");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xMsrcZ/1).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([-*/+])` - Capturing group 1: a `-`, `*`, `/` or `+`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

See a [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/UshGme):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("65+4*5/6", "65   + 4 * 5/ 6", "65+ 4* 5  /6");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println("\"" + str.replaceAll("\\s*([-*/+])\\s*", " $1 ") + "\"");
// => "65 + 4 * 5 / 6"
// => "65 + 4 * 5 / 6"
// => "65 + 4 * 5 / 6"
```